# converting a given file to PDF

Tags: php, .net, pdf, pdf-generation, fpdf

hey all,
is there any way to convert a given file (this could be of any type) in to a pdf file in .net or php?

eg: suppose there is a upload link to upload your file of any type(word,excel,autocad,images..) and once the upload button is clicked the uploaded file should be converted into a pdf.

i checked out fpdf.but according to my knowledge all file types cannot be converted.a module to plugin to the CMS would also be fine.

Comment: nothing can convert *every* file to pdf, but specific tools for various file types exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FPDF does support images. I know because I have used it recently.

If you are wanting a pure PHP solution, you can use the [PHP COM functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php) along with Word or Excel on the server to open up those files then copy the data out.

If I were you though, I would use Google. Load the doc into [Google Docs](http://code.google.com/apis/documents/docs/3.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#UploadingDocs) then export it as a new format with the API.

Comment: FPDF allows to generate custom PDF's. If one can interpret a file, then it can be written down as PDF.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of 3rd party solutions available [such as this one](http://www.muhimbi.com/Products/PDF-Converter-Services/summary.aspx), which is optimised for use on the server and accessible from any web services capable environment, including .net. Supports loads of file types including MS-Office based documents.

Disclaimer, I worked on this product so consider me biased. Having said that, it works very well.